# Get type of Interface with MS Unity

Tags: c#, unity-container

I have the following class that contains logic to obtain the type associated with an interface:

```
public class Token
{
    public IJwtClaimSet JwtClaims { get; private set; }

    public Token(EmployeeAuthToken token)
    {
      IUnityContainer container = UnityCommon.GetContainer();
      IJwtClaimSet jwtClaims = container.Resolve<IJwtClaimSet>();

      JwtClaims = TokenBuilder.ClaimSet(jwt, jwtClaims.GetType());
    }
}
```

My question:
Is there a way to obtain the resolved type from Unity without creating a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may retrieve registration informations :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660863(v=pandp.20).aspx

```
var destinationType = container.Registrations
    .Where(r => r.RegisteredType == typeof(IJwtClaimSet))
    .Select(r => r.MappedToType)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

But it may not work (injection by instance, ...) so the safest way is to resolve it or maybe you can register another object containing information type.